# PyQt5. Как ПРАВИЛЬНО менять дизайн, если он был сделан в QT Designer?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qt-designer

Задавал вопрос по объяснению с `PyQt5` & `Qt Designer`.
Ответ был дан, но так же такое замечания:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По этому поводу создаю отдельно эту тему, чтобы спросить следующие:

1. Правильно ли я создал структуру своей программы? Ведь раньше я всё делал в одном файле, и без функции `__init__` и `super().__init__()`
2. Как правильно редактировать интерфейс? Смотрим по примеру из файлов ниже. Мне нужно добавить ещё одну кнопку или же переименовать старую. Разве не правильно и легче зайти в файл ресурсов (fromqt.py) и там например строчку:

   self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))

...Просто исправить `"PushButton"` на нужное нам имя? Или же скопировать старую кнопку и добавить ещё одну. По такому принципу я делал программу до этого.

3. Так же есть вариант, раз у нас файл ресурсов это отдельный файл, то просто зайти в `qt designer`, предварительно сохранив старую версию в `.ui` и просто добавить новые изменения, сохранить файл и просто заменить старый файл ресурсов на новый?

Но если учитывать заметку наведенную от автора ответа, получается что это не правильный метод изменения интерфейса.

Просьба помочь разобраться с этим. (Буду очень благодарен за наведенный пример).

Прикрепляю файлы:

**main.py:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from fromqt import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)


def run():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

**fromqt.py:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(914, 553)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 260, 131, 51))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 170, 111, 41))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.label.clear)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "dsadasddasdasd"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `Разве не правильно и легче зайти в файл ресурсов (fromqt.py)` правильно если у вас нет `ui` файла, от которого вы этого скрипт сгенерировали. Т.е. лучше открыть `ui` файл в дизайнере qt и поменять там, после перегенерировать `ui` в `py`. Кст, названия полей относятся к значениям objectName из `ui`. Еще вы можете поменять значения прям в `__init__` у `MainWindow`, но я бы советовал все-таки вариант с `ui` или `fromqt.py:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильный вариант, у нас в третьем вопросе.

- зайти в `qt designer`, сделать изменения в `.ui`;
- сконвертировать `.ui` в `fromqt.py`;
  Обратите внимание на строку в `fromqt.py` -

  ## WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!
- запускайте `main.py` с новым дизайном.

Но если вдруг вы потеряли файл `.ui` и у вас сейчас нет времени его нарусовать,
а надо срочно что-то добавит ли изменить, тогда смотрим ниже:

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from fromqt import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.label.clear)   

        self.newButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Новая кнопка", self.centralwidget)
        self.newButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 260, 131, 51))  
        self.newButton.clicked.connect(self.click_newButton)         
    
    def click_newButton(self):
        self.label.setText("Hello World")

def run():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

**fromqt.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(914, 553)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 260, 131, 51))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 170, 111, 41))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
#        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.label.clear)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "dsadasddasdasd"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**UPDATE**

> Ещё не большой вопрос, не хочу уже создавать для него отдельную тему. Подскажите пожалуйста, что значит. Он как то влияет на расположения виджетов? Центрирует..? Вы использовали его в строчке, где создавали новую кнопку, а точнее:
>
> class MainWindow(..)
>
> ...
>
> self.newButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Новая кнопка", self.centralwidget)

---

Это не не большой вопрос, отдельная тема для большого разговора.

Если коротко:

```
QPushButton::QPushButton(const QString &text, QWidget *parent = nullptr)
Создает кнопку с родителем `parent`и текстом `text`.
```

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html#QPushButton-1

виджет без родителя - это окно. **Попробуйте пример ниже.**
Поэтому все что мы хотим показать в главном окне должно иметь родителя основного виджета приложения.

В нашем случае Класс `QMainWindow` предоставляет главное окно приложения.
`QMainWindow` - это особый класс.
`QMainWindow` имеет свой собственный `layout`, к которому вы можете добавить
`QToolBars`, `QDockWidgets`, `QMenuBar` и `QStatusBar`.
Макет имеет центральную область, которая может быть занята любым виджетом.

У нас этот 'любой виджет' - это:

```
self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
```

**Qt Main Window Framework** читаем здесь https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework

Расположение виджетов - это также отдельная большая тема.
В нашем случае мы используем абсолютное позиционирование, которое осущестляется:

```
self.newButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 260, 131, 51))
```

этот способ не практичный.

Вам надо изучить классы `QBoxLayout`, `QFormLayout`, `QGridLayout`, ...
для дальнейшего разговора.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from fromqt import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.label.clear)   

#        self.newButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Новая кнопка", self.centralwidget)   # ---
        self.newButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Новая кнопка")                        # +++
        self.newButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 260, 131, 51))  
        self.newButton.clicked.connect(self.click_newButton)  
        self.newButton.show()                                                         # +++
    
    def click_newButton(self):
        self.label.setText("Hello World")

def run():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ещё не большой вопрос, не хочу уже создавать для него отдельную тему.
Подскажите пожалуйста, что значит. Он как то влияет на расположения виджетов? Центрирует..?
Вы использовали его в строчке, где создавали новую кнопку, а точнее:

class MainWindow(..)
                     ...self.newButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Новая кнопка", self.centralwidget)

Comment: @VitalikShchudlo я добавил некоторые пояснения в свой ответ.